# Do I have to pay customs taxes for a returned article?

Tags: shipping, customs-law

I live in France, I ordered an item from the United States and I didn't like it. I returned it and the parcel status is:

> Inbound Into Customs, Your item is being processed by United States Customs.

Can US customs ask me to pay another tax for an article I returned? I've already paid a tax in France when the article arrived through French customs.

Comment: The recipient is liable for the customs duty.  You are the sender.  If customs charges duty and the recipient declines to pay, I think they'll seize the goods and either destroy them or auction them off.  In this case, however, I doubt any duty would be payable since the item is returning to the US, not entering for the first time.

Comment: @phoog but how can they knwo it's a retuned artcile, nothing specifies it, only the address of the company seeling the good

Comment: If they tell the recipient that duty is payable, the recipient can inform them of the article's history at that point.  If they don't charge duty in the first place, of course, it doesn't matter whether they know.

Comment: Items originating in the USA and returned to the USA unimproved are not subject to any US customs duties. In the future, you may want to supplement your  markings on the package to include "US goods being returned", in order to expedite things.

Comment: Great question. I have no idea what the answer is.

Comment: for update : I didnt pay customs taxes :)